# Type of field 7 in auth response message of google cast protocol v2

Tags: reverse-engineering, chromecast, google-cast

The Google Cast protocol v2 has widely been reverse-engineered and is therefore already well-known. A good example of this is the [Cast v2 Node library repository on GitHub](https://github.com/thibauts/node-castv2) which includes a detailed description of the cast v2 protocol.

However, whilst writing my own implementation of the protocol in Java using Netty, I realized that the auth response message is way more complex than described in the linked repository.

According to the repository, the message should look like:

```proto
message AuthResponse {
  required bytes signature = 1;
  required bytes client_auth_certificate = 2;
  repeated bytes client_ca = 3;
}
```

However, the client sends 3 more fields. They have the indices 4, 6 and 7.

Field 4 is of wiretype `VARINT` and stands, as far as I know, for the SignatureAlgorithm the Cast-enabled device (Chromecast Gen2 and Chromecast Audio) has been challenged with.

Field 6 is also of type `VARINT`, but I have no idea what it stands for. During testing, it always had the value 0. (Maybe it stands for the `client_ca` certificate used for signing the `client_auth_certificate`?)

Field 7 is of wiretype `LENGTH_DELIMITED`. It is definetly not an UTF-8 encoded String since printing it out results in an unreadable mess. However, the sequence printed out contains the complete address that's also been used in the `client_ca` and `client_auth_certificate`, so I believe it has something to do with it. I've already tested whether this might be a certificate or RSA key, but both tests were negative. A file containing the raw byte sequence can be found [here](https://github.com/thibauts/node-castv2/files/3054356/field.7.txt).

This brings me finally to my question:

Do you know what fields 6 and 7 stand for? Guesses based on the file's structure are also highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As I've found out, the protocol is practically open-source since the Chromium project includes the corresponding .proto-files in order to support streaming on Cast-enabled devices.

The complete protocol can be found here: https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/master/components/cast_channel/proto/cast_channel.proto

The structure of the AuthResponse message is therefore

```proto
message AuthResponse {
  required bytes signature = 1;
  required bytes client_auth_certificate = 2;
  repeated bytes intermediate_certificate = 3;
  optional SignatureAlgorithm signature_algorithm = 4
      [default = RSASSA_PKCS1v15];
  optional bytes sender_nonce = 5;
  optional HashAlgorithm hash_algorithm = 6 [default = SHA1];
  optional bytes crl = 7;
}
```